# Dual-screen Multimedia Control Suite for Linux (like Screen Monkey)

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, media, presentations

I'm looking for some linux software to manage and control a dual monitor/multi screen setup for use in professional-like presentations (ie: monitor1=control, monitor2=projector/audience). I have the dual-monitor configured with my gnome desktop running over both monitors (that's the easy part).

What I'm looking for is a neat/seamless way to switch between, say, OpenOffice Impress, DVD Player, VLC live video, Lyricue, other software on monitor2. To have monitor2 shown to the audience and run neat presentations of DVDs, Slideshows, etc. whilst controlling it from monitor1. I can run slideshows, play a DVD on monitor2 (drag & drop VLC on monitor2, and go fullscreen) etc. but this is rather messy in a presentation environment.

I found this software: [Screen Monkey](http://www.screenmonkey.co.uk/). Looks like an excellent windows equivalent for what I want to do.

Is there anything similar for linux? For Gnome, KDE, anything else X based?

Thanks, SamJ

**Edit:** For some clarity, I'll be using the OO.org Impress Presenter's Console extension, and I basically want something akin to that for multimedia playback, to be able to jump a DVD movie up onto monitor 2, whilst keeping the DVD controls on monitor1, same thing with video streams, etc. But the aim is to be able to change seamlessly between Impress, DVD, stream, etc. without the audience knowing. (I'll be using a black wallpaper/background, the key thing is getting the different programs up and down discretely, and keeping the controls on monitor1.)

Answer (score 1):

Screen Monkey so far seems kind of unique. I just started using it on windows7 as an alternative for Lyricue on Ubuntu. Never got the dual graphics going with the ATI built-in video under Ubuntu, so was networking lyricue over two computers (one computer fried from bad power, cheep triple tap in an extension cord).

Screen Monkey does the song lyrics as well as powerpoint graphics (the OpenOffice API does not present the program author a way to use it embedded in his program).

The current version (SM3.4) uses Internet Explorer, but the next may be able to use Firefox. This would be an improvement, because Adobe does not have a 64bit flash version for windows, and if you have Screen Monkey installed as 64 bit, it will try to use 64 bit flash (through IE ?). So a 64 bit warning to you.

It's not exactly your question. Hope this is some help.